# Неправильно работает анимация с OnTouchListener

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, по нажатию на кнопку open должна открываться зеленая панель(RL_panel_color) во весь экран с панелькой в центре(как на фото). Потом при КАСАНИИ на зеленую область панели(RL_panel_color) она должна плавно исчезать. 
Почему мой код криво работает, первый раз срабатывает как надо, а потом при нажатии на любую область экрана выскакивает панель с анимацией?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/MainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true">


<!-- отдельная панель - выбрать цвет для линий -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_panel_color"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false"
    android:background="#08a793"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="18dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#2c3644">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#c9ccde"
            android:text="Цвет линий"
            android:background="#fa152130"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


<Button
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="open"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#445b71"
    android:onClick="onButton_open_Click"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

anim, fade_pnl_color.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500"
android:fillAfter="true">
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="0" />
</set>
```

.....

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RelativeLayout RL_panel_color;//панель на весь экран

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RL_panel_color = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RL_panel_color);


    //ПЛАВНО скрыть панель
    RL_panel_color.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                final Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_pnl_color);
                RL_panel_color.startAnimation(a);
                a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                    @Override

                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        RL_panel_color.setVisibility(View.GONE);}

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                });

            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}


//открыть панель
public void onButton_open_Click(View view) {
    RL_panel_color.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

На будущее: лучше править созданый вопрос, чем удалять и создавать заново. У меня сейчас было оповещение о вашем комментарии в тарой теме, но при клике по нему я получаю 404, нехорошо :)

Я бы делал это несколько иначе. Во-первых, точно не стоит вешать анимацию в onTouchEvent. Когда ставите видимость GONE объект может не пропасть с разметки до принудительного вызова requestLayout родительского ViewGroup. А в случае с RelativeLayout не удивлюсь, если он и после этого останется "трогаемым".  То есть вы объекта не видите, но лайоут знает его расположение и может передать ему событие касания. Вообще RealtiveLayout едва ли не самый тяжелый и непредсказуемый контейнер в андроид, в вашем случае FrameLayout хватит. Если будут еще элементы - используйте ConstraintLayout, он шустрее и гибче.

Я предлагаю сделать так. В активити создаем поле

```
Animator animator = null
```

Если оно null или animator.isRunning() == false, то наш зеленый контейнер в покое, в противном случае идет анимация. В активити можно переопределить dispatchTouchEvent, где мы скрываем объект, если он видим(не GONE) и нет текущей анимации:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(RL_panel_color.getVisibility() != View.GONE && (animator == null || !animator.isRunning())){
        Animator a = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(RL_panel_color, View.alpha, 0f)
        a.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        RL_panel_color.setVisibility(View.GONE);}

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
                })
        a.start()
        animator = a
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Аниматор действительно стоит создавать каждый раз новый. В данном случае это не принципиально, но в более сложных ситуациях это может быть важно. При таком подходе мы снимаем с объекта ответственность за его отображение/сокрытие, перекладывая эту функцию на его родителя, плюс имеем некоторое конкретное состояние объекта, которое заблокирует ненужные анимации ни смотря ни на что. Помимо перехвата в Activity.dispatchTouchEvent можно наследовать от любого ViewGroup свой класс, указать в разметке самый верхний RelativeLayout как объект этого класса, и перехватывать нажатия в методе onInterceptTouchEvent()

Comment: Спасибо, правда Ваш пример тоже не работает так как надо. Я уже решил проблему, нормально заработало только через ObjectAnimator.